# How to count Stored procedure with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
EXEC  [dbo].[sp_get_lowqtyproduct]
```

I want to know how many data in this Stored procedure

Comment: You want to know how many rows that procedure returns?

Comment: yes brother 
Example: i want to know how many rows and i get this count to show on thymeleaf

Comment: I don't know that MySQL has an equivalent to mssql's `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` but that's something you could look into. You could also create a copy of the procedure that specifically returns only the count using the same logic.

Comment: The published code is MSSQL/sql-server not mysql - you might want to change the tags to attract the appropriate contributors.